# RNCryptor decrypt message from UITextview iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rncryptor

I am using `RNCryptor` to encrypt a message from a `UITextview` and send this message. I want to do the reverse action. ie, when the receiver copy the encrypted message from his inbox and copy to the `UITextView` in the iOS application and when he press decrypt, he wants to see the original message. how can I decrypt the message since it is in the form of `NSString` not `NSData`?
 I tried to convert using following code before the RNCryptor conversion. But I failed.

```
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

`str` is the string from the inbox.

This is the encryption and decryption code:

```
NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:kPASSWORD
                                           error:&error];

NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:datatoDecrypt
                                    withPassword:kPASSWORD
                                           error:&error];
```

Comment: RNCryptor uses `Base64` encoding, not UTF8. Try using NSData's new built-in Base64 encoding features.

Comment: RNCryptor does not use Base64 encoding. It works only with NSData directly for plaintext and ciphertext. The caller is free to create the NSData any way desired. The above code looks ok. It's probably an error in creating  "datatoDecrypt".

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the error message by the following code:

```
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"cannot decrypt with error %@", [error description]);
}
```